# Applying Seq.map using 2 sequences to a method which takes 2 parameters

Tags: f#, seq, partial-application

I'm writing a quick DB perf test, and chose F# so I can get more practice.

I've created a method, `measureSelectTimes`, which has the signature `Guid list * Guid list -> IDbCommand -> TimeSpan * TimeSpan`.

Then, I call it:

```
let runTests () =
    let sqlCeConn : IDbConnection = initSqlCe() :> IDbConnection
    let sqlServerConn : IDbConnection = initSqlServer() :> IDbConnection
    let dbsToTest = [ sqlCeConn; sqlServerConn ]
    let cmds : seq<IDbCommand> = dbsToTest |> Seq.map initSchema
    let ids : seq<Guid list * Guid list> = cmds |> Seq.map loadData
    let input = Seq.zip ids cmds
    let results = input |> Seq.map (fun i -> measureSelectTimes (fst i) (snd i))
    // ...
```

I've annotated explicitly with types to clarify.

What I can't figure out is how to call `measureSelectTimes` without the lambda. I'd like to partially apply the `ids` to it like this: `ids |> Seq.map measureSelectTimes` but then I don't know what to do with the resulting partially applied functions to then map onto the `cmds`. What's the syntax for this?

Comment: BTW, you can write your lambda as `(fun (id,cmd)->measureSelectTimes id cmd)`. (It's unrelated to the question, though)

Comment: @Dmitry - thanks, good stuff. This is why I posted the question, I need to expand my F# vocab.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use `Seq.map2`:

```
Seq.map2 measureSelectTimes ids cmds
```

Or

```
(ids, cmds) ||> Seq.map2 measureSelectTimes
```

Comment: `let partial = Seq.map2 measureSelectTimes ids`, indeed.  It's so obvious and easy... when you see the solution. But before I saw it it did'n even crossed my mind. :-(    +1

Comment: This is what I was looking for; I didn't see how Seq.map2 worked, but this cleared it up. Thanks also @Dmitry for how to express the result as a partial to apply, which is what I was ultimately thinking of. +1

Comment: +1 for teaching me a new operator - where did "||>" come from!? It's not on the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233228.aspx) page.

Answer (score 3):

Your `measureSelectTimes` function takes two arguments as separate arguments, but you instead need a function that takes them as a tuple. One option is to just change the function to take a tuple (if it is logical for the arguments to be tupled).

Alternative, you can write a cobinator that turns a function taking two arguments into a function taking tuple. This is usually called `uncurry` and it exists in some functional language:

```
let uncurry f (a, b) = f a b
```

Then you can write:

```
input |> Seq.map (uncurry measureSelectTimes)
```

This looks okay for a simple use like this, but I think that using combinators too much in F# is not a good idea as it makes code difficult to read for less experienced functional programmers. I would probably write something like this (because I find that more readable):

```
[ for (time1, time2) in input -> measureSelectTimes time1 time2 ]
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer and the 2 new tools of using an uncurry function and a list comprehension to solve it. Also, thanks for the book.

Answer (score 0):

One approach is to change the signature of `measureSelectTimes` to

```
(Guid list * Guid list) * IDbCommand -> TimeSpan * TimeSpan
```

Then you can change the `map` call to

```
let results = input |> Seq.map measureSelectTimes
// or
let results = Seq.map measureSelectTimes input
```

Comment: Yea, I thought of this, but I knew there must be another approach than to need to change the method sig.